# Retrofit - Receive JSON Array Always Return NULL

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have code :

**InterfaceAPI:**

```
@GET("/api/getUserAsset?")
Call<MyObject> getUserAsset(@Query("user_id") String userId);
```

The Library said : HTTP OK 200

**MyObject.java :**

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
```

**JSON Response from API :**

```
[{"name":"bob"}]
```

When i call the method `getUserAsset` i always get NULL, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON response is an array.

it should be : `{"name" : "bob"}` if you want to be able to deserialize it correctly.